# mysql error when using over() and an alias

Tags: mysql, function, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Using the phpMyAdmin console and MariaDB 10.2, if I combine the over() function with an alias I get a variety of errors:

```
SELECT AVG(foo) OVER() AS bar FROM some_table
```

- an alias was previously found (near bar)
- unexpected token (near bar)
- an alias was expected (near ) <-- just an empty space

these statements with either one function don't give me errors

```
SELECT AVG(foo) AS bar FROM some_table

SELECT AVG(foo) OVER() FROM some_table
```

All of the stuff I can find implies that these errors come from basic mistakes, like having a comma out of place, or using reserved keywords as aliases. I don't think I'm doing any of that.

Comment: What is the purpose of using `OVER()` here ?

Comment: It's just a simplified example of the syntax pattern. I'm trying to use OVER() to calculate linear regression in a more complicated query. In order to calculate linear regression I need to do an operation with each individual value and with the average for that group of values.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the linter that phpMyAdmin uses for verifying syntax hasn't been updated for this syntax that seems to have been introduced with MariaDB 10.2. While it's annoying, you can ignore the warnings and run your query anyway.

I've opened a bug report about it at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/issues/197, where you can follow along until the bug is fixed.